# How to preload specific area of Google Map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Let's say you open this map:

https://www.google.com.au/maps/@-33.8654593,151.2082297,15z

When you pan, you see that the map is being loaded. It's of course better now, as maps are vectors drawn in a canvas element. But still you need to wait for a while.

The same happens when you use `panTo` method of a Map object in Google Maps API ([docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)). And this is mainly my problem. I want to pan using JavaScript to some area of a Google Map which is already preloaded, so user see the whole view sharp even when animating.

Is there any way to specify a region of a map to preload so you don't see it loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @Gady's answer I prepared a trick which did a job for me - I made a map just bigger than my screen, so invisible areas are loaded as well. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { width: 300%; left: -100%; height: 300%; top: -100%; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

It's copied from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#HelloWorld) + my little tweak. Remember to replace `API_KEY` with working key generated [here](https://console.developers.google.com/).

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately there is no way to do this as part of the JavaScript API.